# How do I fix audio/video sync in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, sync, merge

I have a video in 1080p but for some dumb reason, the audio is only stereo. I also have the same video in 480p but the audio is 5.1. I've merged several videos taking the 1080p video from one source and the 5.1 audio from the other with minor difficulty: sometimes I would have to shift the audio a second or two. However, this video isn't so easy. The audio is early for the entire video and seems to get further off as the video nears the end. If I shift the audio, I get audio that starts off behind but still ends up ahead. I'm using the following code:
`ffmpeg -i input_0.mp4 -i input_1.mp4 -c copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -shortest out.mp4`
I've used "-itsoffset" both positive and negative values in front of either the video or audio sources and I've tried them without the "-shortest"

Comment: Check the frame rate for both, check the audio sampling frequency for both. Make sure they're the same or you'll have to include that in your calculations.

Comment: I did see that the fps of the first (video) was 24 where as the second (audio) was 23.98. Further, the first was a few seconds longer with 1 of those being on the front end. I can cut that but it looks like I still have about 2 seconds to account for. The audio of both is 48kHz. What am I getting myself into?

Comment: I've found that using a combination of this code with the original work:
```ffmpeg -i "input.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:a]atempo=0.9993[a]" -map "[a]" -acodec aac -b:a 512k input_1.mp4```
I can't use -c copy, which stinks but I don't think I can stretch/shrink audio without re-encoding. I could probably merge these two codes into one but this is quicker when I also need to adjust the delay. If you know a better way, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: You're going to have to time-scale one or other of the videos, which will mean re-encoding.

Comment: Thank you. This works most of the time. I do have one a/v sync issue that is beyond me: I've created a new question for it as I believe it deserves it's own answer. Time-scale seems to be an issue but I do not see any such command to fix it.

Comment: you can also pass an integer fraction to atempo: `atempo=23980/24000`

Comment: "I've created a new question for it" - please add link

Comment: a problem with `atempo` is that it will change the pitch (frequencies of all tones) of the audio stream, so voices and music will sound either higher or lower. in most cases, this is not desired. instead of `atempo` you should use a "timestretch" filter like `ffmpeg -af rubberband=tempo=23980/24000`. see also [How to change pitch and tempo together, reliably with ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564451/how-to-change-pitch-and-tempo-together-reliably-with-ffmpeg) and [Piping Sox and FFMPEG together](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98876/piping-sox-and-ffmpeg-together)